# Shell Script To Write PostgreSQL SQL Query Results In To CSV Format

Tags: postgresql, shell, postgresql-9.4

I need to create a Linux shell script to run a PostgreSQL SQL query and  export the results in CSV Format. By doing some research I came to know there are two ways I can do it such as below:

1. using an SQL query

   ```
   COPY table_name TO ‘file_name.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
   ```
2. using `psql`

   ```
   \copy table_name to 'filename.csv’ csv header
   ```

I have tried both from SQL server out of which I found the first method needs administrative permission, which I don't want.

I have tried the second method and am able to write the PostgreSQL query output to a CSV file as well, but now I need to do that from a shell script, where I am facing the below issue. I am writing inside the script as follows:

```
psql -U username -d database -c $'
\copy(WITH var(collectionMonth) as (values(\'$collectionMonth\'))
SELECT CONCAT(var.collectionMonth, LPAD(mfv2.integer_value::text,2,\'0\')) as "collection_date" FROM var,
meta_field_value mfv2 WHERE mfv2.meta_field_name_id=8 TO \'/home/my.csv\' csv HEADER;'
```

It shows “syntax error near \copy”. How to fix this? I know the error is because of the `\` in front of the `copy` command.

Answer (score 2):

Your quoting is off.

Best is to use a “here document”:

```
psql -U username -d database <<EOF
\copy (WITH var(collectionMonth) as (values('$collectionMonth')) SELECT CONCAT(var.collectionMonth, LPAD(mfv2.integer_value::text,2,'0')) as "collection_date" FROM var, meta_field_value mfv2 WHERE mfv2.meta_field_name_id=8) TO '/home/my.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', HEADER)
EOF
```

Comment: with using EOF also I am getting error "invalid command \copy("

Comment: @abhisek insert space between `\copy` and `(` as shown above.

Comment: @Abelisto , I got it now. It's not the space issue . for \copy the complete command should be in one line.